# Takes awhile longer

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

I heard someone say

> It might take awhile longer for the document to be signed
>   It might take a bit longer for the document to be signed

Is it grammatical and idiomatic? What they meant is that it might take slightly longer for the document to be signed.

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence, you need to replace 'awhile' with 'a while'. 'A while' (noun) means 'a period of time', and 'awhile' (adverb) means 'for a time'. Examples:

> It will take a while for your meal to be ready.
>
> I will rest awhile.

[While versus awhile](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/while-versus-awhile)

Your second sentence is fine, but using 'a bit' to mean 'a short while or period of time' is informal and conversational.